# Search in every field with a fixed parameter

Tags: elasticsearch

Perhaps it's a basic question; by the way, I need to search in every indexed field and to have a specific fixed value for another field.
How can I do it?

Currently I have a simple: `query( "aValue", array_of_models )`

I tried many options without success, for example:

```
query({
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "query": "aValue",
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "published": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I would prefer to avoid to specify the fields to search in because I use the same search params for different models.

Comment: 2x bool must queries should satisfy your requirement.  One for the fixed term, one for the match in any field.  The only way I am aware of to avoid having to specify fields (unless you use a wildcard) is to use `_all`.  The use of `_all` is discouraged though, so its best to specify fields.

Comment: @ryanlutgen it seems strange to me that the generic form ( query( "value" ) ) search everywhere but if I specify some options with the DSL I can't do the same...

Comment: Currently I'm using `_all` - I have just wrote a reply with my current working payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, perhaps it's not optimized but works:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "_all": "aValue"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "published": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I accepted my own answer for now, if someone has a better solution please write it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly your intention.

The *_all* field is as default enabled. So if you have no special mapping every indexed field **value** is added as text string to the *_all* field.

You can use the

- Query String Query, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html
- Simple Query String Query, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html

With a simple query like this, that should work for you.

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "aValue",
      "fields": []
    }
  }
}
```

Both query types contains parameters, that should suffice your use case IMHO.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, I need to search in all fields AND to have a specific value for a specific field

Comment: The current example searches in **all** fields, if you put certain fields into it, it will limit its search only to these fields. You can filter for the specific field, but without any more information, it is hard to tell.